# Android PullToRefreshGridView doesn't scroll to the first item

Tags: android, gridview

I m using a PullToRefreshGridView . But i got a problem.
When my adapter changed , it doesnt scroll to the first row in PullToRefreshGridView .
I already used these method: scrollTo , setSelection but no result.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What PullToRefresh are you using for?

Comment: im using it for :"when i pull it down/up , i will refresh its adapter content" it look like in "Facebook mobile app"